# Coupled Differential equation of second order in matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, systems-of-equations

I have a problem solving a system of differential equations of second order in matlab:
$$ \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}= \frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\\ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= \frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
    \end{array} \right. $$ I know, that i need to rewrite $x=u_1$ and$\frac{dx}{dt}=u_2 $  (same with $y=s_1$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=s_2$ ) and make it to a system of 4 differential equations of the second order. 
$$\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}u'_1=u_2\\ u'_2= \frac{-u_1}{(s_1^2+u_1^2)^{3/2}}\\s'_1=s_2\\ s'_2= \frac{-s_1}{(s_1^2+u_1^2)^{3/2}}
    \end{array} \right. $$I know that i need to use runge-kutta and ode45 in matlab, but i don't know how to make everything work. How do I set up a system of 4 differential equations and make it work with matlab?

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) for `ode45` and [this general overview](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html) of Matlab's ODE solvers and doing the examples provided. Don't think you can dive in and magically use this complex function to get answers without learning. Then you might also check out [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/03/25/solving) and [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/04/08/odes) on how to write your equations symbolically and convert them to numeric code.

Comment: @user2149616: http://www.math.purdue.edu/academic/files/courses/2005spring/MA266/ode45.pdf

Comment: Cross-posted verbatim at [SciComp.StackExchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16358/coupled-differential-equation-of-second-order-in-matlab). Please [*do not*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) [cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette).